# write_room Full - tty Driver

Tags: linux-kernel, tty

I am writing a new tty serial driver. I have a count in the driver which tells the number of bytes sent to the write function. The count will reduce after successful write. when the write_room is full, the application waits and when the write_room is available it tries to write the next set of data. At this time the tty driver tries to write the same previous data character by character. The tty_io.c tty_put_char function is called. Unable to resolve this issue, request inputs here.

Comment: *tty* is using circular buffer. You have to move its pointers whenever data comes from one or the other side.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So you mean the tty core will have a circular buffer and that pointer must be modified by the tty driver ? FYI, i have not used any circular buffer in my driver.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i tried the belwo implementation changes: 
1. I disable echos in serial application. 
2. In the tty driver, after i get response of successful write, i call tty_wakeup of the tty driver.

Doing the above partially resolved my issues. 
But this does not work consistantly. Request inputs here on my approach.